# How to change Scrollbar's thickness?

Tags: flutter

Scrollbar widget in Flutter seems to have a fixed thickness of 6. I think the Scrollbar looks ugly, it is too thick. Also if I compare Flutter Scrollbar to scrollbars in other apps in my device, they all look different (they look better).

Can I change the Scrollbar thickness without creating a new Scrollbar widget?

I had an idea to force Scrollbar partially out of screen to make it look thinner, but I don't know how to do that.

I am using the Scrollbar with a ListView.

Answer (score 5):

Just change the `thickness` property from scrollbar theme data:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final double _thickness = 2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        scrollbarTheme: ScrollbarThemeData().copyWith(
          thickness: MaterialStateProperty.all(_thickness),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a relatively simple workaround which to wrap the Scrollbar in a Stack widget and add to Stack a Container which will hide part of the Scrollbar. There will be a small 'white' margin in the right edge of the screen but you will see similar margin e.g. in OS settings views (at least in Galaxy S7 settings app). Sample code (notice that this is for Android only, not tested in iOS):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
    fit: StackFit.loose,
    children: <Widget>[
      Scrollbar(
        child: buildListView(),
      ),
      Container(
        width: 3,
        color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
      )
    ],
  );
}
```